# Kafka and Pinot -- Message not sent

Tags: apache-kafka, data-science, apache-pinot

I am trying to ingres data through kafka and json file and running this command:

```
bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:19092 --topic mytopic < $PDATA_HOME/opt_flatten_json.json
```

But I am getting error:

```
Exception while executing a state transition task mystats__0__0__20210319T0430Z
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_282]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_282]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_282]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_282]
    at org.apache.helix.messaging.handling.HelixStateTransitionHandler.invoke(HelixStateTransitionHandler.java:404) ~[pinot-all-0.7.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT-d87755899eccba3554e9cc39a1439d5ecb53aaac]
    at org.apache.helix.messaging.handling.HelixStateTransitionHandler.handleMessage(HelixStateTransitionHandler.java:331) [pinot-all-0.7.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT-d87755899eccba3554e9cc39a1439d5ecb53aaac]
    at org.apache.helix.messaging.handling.HelixTask.call(HelixTask.java:97) [pinot-all-0.7.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT-d87755899eccba3554e9cc39a1439d5ecb53aaac]
    at org.apache.helix.messaging.handling.HelixTask.call(HelixTask.java:49) [pinot-all-0.7.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT-d87755899eccba3554e9cc39a1439d5ecb53aaac]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_282]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_282]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_282]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_282]
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Direct buffer memory
    at java.nio.Bits.reserveMemory(Bits.java:695) ~[?:1.8.0_282]
    at java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.<init>(DirectByteBuffer.java:123) ~[?:1.8.0_282]
    at java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(ByteBuffer.java:311) ~[?:1.8.0_282]
    at org.apache.pinot.core.segment.memory.PinotByteBuffer.allocateDirect(PinotByteBuffer.java:39) ~[pinot-all-0.7.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT-d87755899eccba3554e9cc39a1439d5ecb53aaac]
    at org.apache.pinot.core.segment.memory.PinotDataBuffer.allocateDirect(PinotDataBuffer.java:116) ~[pinot-all-0.7.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT-d87755899eccba3554e9cc39a1439d5ecb53aaac]
    at org.apache.pinot.core.io.writer.impl.DirectMemoryManager.allocateInternal(DirectMemoryManager.java:53) ~[pinot-all-0.7.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT-d87755899eccba3554e9cc39a1439d5ecb53aaac]
    at org.apache.pinot.core.io.readerwriter.RealtimeIndexOffHeapMemoryManager.allocate(RealtimeIndexOffHeapMemoryManager.java:79) ~[pinot-all-0.7.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT-d87755899eccba3554e9cc39a1439d5ecb53aaac]
    at org.apache.pinot.core.realtime.impl.forward.FixedByteMVMutableForwardIndex.addDataBuffer(FixedByteMVMutableForwardIndex.java:162) ~[pinot-all-0.7.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT-d87755899eccba3554e9cc39a1439d5ecb53aaac]
    at org.apache.pinot.core.realtime.impl.forward.FixedByteMVMutableForwardIndex.<init>(FixedByteMVMutableForwardIndex.java:137) ~[pinot-all-0.7.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT-d87755899eccba3554e9cc39a1439d5ecb53aaac]
    at org.apache.pinot.core.indexsegment.mutable.MutableSegmentImpl.<init>(MutableSegmentImpl.java:307) ~[pinot-all-0.7.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT-d87755899eccba3554e9cc39a1439d5ecb53aaac]
    at org.apache.pinot.core.data.manager.realtime.LLRealtimeSegmentDataManager.<init>(LLRealtimeSegmentDataManager.java:1270) ~[pinot-all-0.7.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT-d87755899eccba3554e9cc39a1439d5ecb53aaac]
    at org.apache.pinot.core.data.manager.realtime.RealtimeTableDataManager.addSegment(RealtimeTableDataManager.java:324) ~[pinot-all-0.7.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT-d87755899eccba3554e9cc39a1439d5ecb53aaac]
    at org.apache.pinot.server.starter.helix.HelixInstanceDataManager.addRealtimeSegment(HelixInstanceDataManager.java:132) ~[pinot-all-0.7.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT-d87755899eccba3554e9cc39a1439d5ecb53aaac]
    at org.apache.pinot.server.starter.helix.SegmentOnlineOfflineStateModelFactory$SegmentOnlineOfflineStateModel.onBecomeOnlineFromOffline(SegmentOnlineOfflineStateModelFactory.java:164) ~[pinot-all-0.7.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT-d87755899eccba3554e9cc39a1439d5ecb53aaac]
    at org.apache.pinot.server.starter.helix.SegmentOnlineOfflineStateModelFactory$SegmentOnlineOfflineStateModel.onBecomeConsumingFromOffline(SegmentOnlineOfflineStateModelFactory.java:88) ~[pinot-all-0.7.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT-d87755899eccba3554e9cc39a1439d5ecb53aaac]
    ... 12 more
Default rollback method invoked on error. Error Code: ERROR
Message execution failed. msgId: eed5b297-ea20-437e-a0b5-ad4d0be75c3c, errorMsg: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Skip internal error. errCode: ERROR, errMsg: null
Event bcbad381_DEFAULT : Unable to find a next state for resource: mystats_REALTIME partition: mystats__0__0__20210319T0430Z from stateModelDefinitionclass org.apache.helix.model.StateModelDefinition from:ERROR to:CONSUMING
Event c910d226_DEFAULT : Unable to find a next state for resource: mystats_REALTIME partition: mystats__0__0__20210319T0430Z from stateModelDefinitionclass org.apache.helix.model.StateModelDefinition from:ERROR to:CONSUMING
Event d194950f_DEFAULT : Unable to find a next state for resource: mystats_REALTIME partition: mystats__0__0__20210319T0430Z from stateModelDefinitionclass org.apache.helix.model.StateModelDefinition from:ERROR to:CONSUMING
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your Kafka JVM ran out of memory:

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Direct buffer memory
```

This issue seems related to this [ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-5814).

You should set the Environment Variable for Kafka appropriately to your memory needs: f.i. `-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=512m`

Comment: Pinot ran out of memory, not Kafka. Extra information about Pinot realtime table config should be provided to debug the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your Pinot ran out of memory buffer for the realtime table segment. Extra info about the segment and realtime table config is needed to debug further.